# iText PDF Text Extraction with fonts and styles

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

I am using iText to extract text from PDF to a String but I have encountered a problem 
with some PDF. When I tried to extract text, the reader extract only blanks/destroyed text
on SOME pdfs.

Example of destroyed text:

**"th isbe long to t he t est fo r extr act ion tex t"**

**What is the cause of this problem?**

I am thinking of removing the fonts and change the font to a suitable one to be read by 
the reader. I have tried researching about this, but what I found does not help me.

Comment: You already know the generic reasons (as addressed  in Lee's answer) for the difficulties of PDF text extraction from answers to your former questions here. If the pdfs in question are especially cumbersome, you might want to supply them for inspection. It is very unlikely that font replacement will do any good in those cases which already return the text (albeit with funny spaces inserted). In the cases you only retrieve spaces font replacement might help in certain very very special situations, but not in general, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the way text is stored in the PDF file. It just puts letters with information for rendering and location. The text extraction algorithm is smart in that it finds letters that seem to be close together and, if so, it puts them together. If they aren't that close, it puts in some space.

I can't tell you what to do about it, though.